# Connecting go and postgres with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, go, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect a go and a postgres container with docker-compose.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    server:
        build: ./server
        command: gin
        volumes:
            - ./server:/go/src/app
        ports:
            - "8080:3000"
```

At first I was trying with the links command in the docker-compose.yml, but that didn't create any env variables in the server container, so that got me pretty confused. (It's supposed to create SOMETHINGSOMETHING_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR and SOMETHINGSOMETHING_5432_TCP_PORT, isn't it?)

Then I read somewhere I could just use http://postgres as the host, so I tried that. So now this is how my main.go looks like (NOTE: I'm using Gorp for "ORM"):

```
func main() {

    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s host=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        "postgres",
        os.Getenv("DB_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        "http://postgres",
        DB_NAME,
    )

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)

    checkErr(err, "sql.Open failed")


    // construct a gorp DbMap
    dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.PostgresDialect{}}

    // add a table, setting the table name to 'posts' and
    // specifying that the Id property is an auto incrementing PK
    dbmap.AddTableWithName(Todo{}, "todos").SetKeys(true, "Id")

    // create the table. in a production system you'd generally
    // use a migration tool, or create the tables via scripts
    err = dbmap.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
    checkErr(err, "Create tables failed")

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", nil)
}
```

Here's a detailed log of docker-compose up (I get connection refused on port 5432):

```
←[36mserver_1    |←[0m [gin] listening on port 3000
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m This user must also own the server process.
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m Data page checksums are disabled.
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating subdirectories ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m selecting default max_connections ... 100
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating configuration files ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m initializing pg_authid ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m initializing dependencies ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating system views ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating collations ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating conversions ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating dictionaries ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m creating information schema ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m vacuuming database template1 ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m copying template1 to template0 ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m copying template1 to postgres ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m syncing data to disk ... ok
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m Success. You can now start the database server using:
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-08-19 18:31:55 UTC
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m  done
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m server started
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m ALTER ROLE
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m /docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  received fast shutdown request
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  aborting any active transactions
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  shutting down
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  database system is shut down
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m  done
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m server stopped
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-08-19 18:31:57 UTC
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
←[33mpostgres_1  |←[0m LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
←[36mserver_1    |←[0m 2016/08/19 18:32:05 Create tables failed dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused
←[36mserver_1    |←[0m 2016/08/19 18:32:05 http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:3001: getsockopt: connection refused
←[36mserver_1    |←[0m 2016/08/19 18:32:05 Create tables failed dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused
←[36mserver_1    |←[0m 2016/08/19 18:32:05 http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:3001: getsockopt: connection refused
```

So my question is how do I get these to be able to talk to each other and what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try `sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres/yourdbname")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out as I am not actually linking the containers, os.Getenv("DB_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD") was producing an empty string. Added an environment variable with password to the server container in docker-compose.yml and now I can connect to my database.

Answer (score 6):

That a docker networking question.You can read more about it [here.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)
Docker dns does all the hard work, so you can reach each container by the  name you gave it on the compose file.

Posgres url usually works like

```
postgresql://user:password@ip:port/database
```

So for you, it would be something like.

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgresql://user:password@postgres/mydatabase)
```

Note that you do not need the port if postgres is on the standard port (5432).

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful :)

Comment: @Nirri Would you mind accepting this as the correct answer?